# No value for checkbox in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, checkbox

I'm having a problem with the checkbox in the array. I'm working on a script that runs at soccergames (indoor) to keep track of goalscorers and other information like cards (green or red).

Here's the code for the away team table. The problem is with the checkboxes. When unchecked they don't send any value. I need them to send '0' as value when unchecked and '30' when checked.

```
   $sql1="SELECT dbo_doelpunten.TeamRelatieNummer, dbo_doelpunten.aantaldoelpunten, dbo_doelpunten.Deelnemer, dbo_doelpunten.aantalstrafminuten, dbo_Deelnemers.Deelnemer, dbo_Deelnemers.MinutenStrafVerwerkt, dbo_Deelnemers.Doelpunten, dbo_Deelnemers.NaamCombi
    FROM dbo_doelpunten
    LEFT JOIN dbo_Deelnemers
    ON dbo_doelpunten.Deelnemer=dbo_Deelnemers.Deelnemer
    WHERE dbo_doelpunten.TeamRelatieNummer='436'
    ORDER BY dbo_doelpunten.Deelnemer
    ";
    // $sql1="SELECT * FROM dbo_doelpunten WHERE TeamRelatienummer='436'";
    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);

    // Count table rows 
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result1);
    $Deelnemer = array();
    ?>
    <td>
    <table id="table" class="table"  width="400"> 
    <thead> 
    <tr> 
        <th data-sort="int">Nr</th>
        <th data-sort="string">Naam</th>      
        <th data-sort="int">Doelpunten</th> 
        <th data-sort="int">Tijdstraf</th> 
        <th data-sort="int">Rood?</th>
    </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    while($rowuit=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    $e=$rowuit['MinutenStrafVerwerkt'];
    if ($e>='10')
      {
      echo "<tr bgcolor='red'>";
      }
    else
      {
      echo "<tr>";
      }
      ?>
    <td width="50" class="tdata"><input name="Deelnemeruit[]" type="hidden" id="Deelnemeruit" size="10" value="<? echo $rowuit['Deelnemer']; ?>" readonly><? echo $rowuit['Deelnemer']; ?></td>
    <td width="250" class="tdata"><input name="NaamCombiuit[]" type="hidden" id="NaamCombiuit" size="20" value="<? echo $rowuit['NaamCombi']; ?>" readonly><? echo $rowuit['NaamCombi']; ?></td>
    <td width="50" class="tdata"><input name="doelpuntuit[]" type="number" min="0" max="100" size="3" id="doelpuntuit" value="<? echo $rowuit['aantaldoelpunten'] ?>"></td>
    <td width="50" class="tdata"><input name="strafuit[]" type="number" min="0" max="100" size="3" id="strafuit" value="<? echo $rowuit['aantalstrafminuten'] ?>"></td>
    <td width="50" class="tdata"><input name="rooduit[]" type="checkbox" value="30" id="rooduit"></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Creating the array works well and the table is created good. Updating the score, goalscorers and time penalty (green cards) works well except the red card which is an checkbox. Beneath the code for updating the DB

```
$Deelnemerthuis = $_POST['Deelnemerthuis']; 
$NaamCombithuis = $_POST['NaamCombithuis'];
$doelpuntthuis = $_POST['doelpuntthuis']; 
$strafthuis = $_POST['strafthuis']; 
$vlaggerthuis = $_POST['vlaggerthuis']; 
$teamthuis = $_POST['teamthuis']; 
$roodthuis = $_POST['roodthuis'];

$Deelnemeruit = $_POST['Deelnemeruit']; 
$NaamCombiuit = $_POST['NaamCombiuit'];
$doelpuntuit = $_POST['doelpuntuit']; 
$strafuit = $_POST['strafuit']; 
$vlaggeruit = $_POST['vlaggeruit']; 
$teamuit = $_POST['teamuit']; 
$rooduit = $_POST['roodtuit'];




// Check if button name "Submit" is active, do this 
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){

$i=0;
while($i<$count){
$sql3= "UPDATE dbo_doelpunten SET aantaldoelpunten = '" . $doelpuntthuis[$i] . "', aantalstrafminuten = '" . $strafthuis[$i] . "' WHERE wedstrijdid='300' AND  Deelnemer = '" . $Deelnemerthuis[$i] . "'"; 
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);


$sql7= "UPDATE dbo_Deelnemers SET MinutenStrafVerwerkt = MinutenStrafVerwerkt+'" . $roodthuis[$i] . "' WHERE Deelnemer = '" . $Deelnemerthuis[$i] . "'";
$result7=mysql_query($sql7);


$sql4= "UPDATE dbo_doelpunten SET aantaldoelpunten = '" . $doelpuntuit[$i] . "', aantalstrafminuten = '" . $strafuit[$i] . "' WHERE wedstrijdid = '300' AND Deelnemer = '" . $Deelnemeruit[$i] . "' "; 
$result4=mysql_query($sql4);

$sql8= "UPDATE dbo_Deelnemers SET MinutenStrafVerwerkt = MinutenStrafVerwerkt+'" . $rooduit[$i] . "' WHERE Deelnemer = '" . $Deelnemeruit[$i] . "'"; 
$result8=mysql_query($sql8);

$i++;
}
```

How can I get the checkbox have value 0 when unchecked and 30 when checked?

I posted the full code of the page here:
http://pastebin.com/u6xVMmrr

Comment: Do you mean yellow cards?

Comment: nope, i really ment green cards (it's Futsall) and a green card means a time penalty of 2 minutes. Red is sent off for the rest of the game ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkboxes don't send unchecked data, so you have two options:

1. Test for the existance of the checkbox field. If it isn't present, assume a value of 0.
2. Have a hidden form variable with an identical variable name and value of '0', which will get sent on post. If the checkbox (which appears later in the form) is checked, it will overwrite the 0 value with 30.

Comment: thanx monkeymatrix. I tried option 2, but somehow the value of 30 was sent to the next player. Maybe I did something wrong. Will check again!

Comment: Make sure the hidden variable has a value of 0. IF the box is unchecked, it shouldn't send any data! :)

Comment: monkeymatrix. I have this code now:
<td width="50" class="tdata"><input name="rooduit[]" type="checkbox" value="0" id="roodthuis" style="display:none;" checked><input name="rooduit[]" type="checkbox" value="10" id="rooduit"></td>

But when submitting the form the 30 will go to the next player instead of the one that is selected

Comment: You need <input type="hidden" value="0" id="roodthuit" name="rooduit[]"> - sorry I should have been clearer. You use a hidden field, not a hidden checkbox!

Comment: Thanx for the update, unfortunately it's still adding the 30 to the next player. See the page in action: www.srza.org/test.php

Comment: Hmmm, this is confusing. They send 30 when unchecked?!

Comment: no, they send 0 when unchecked. But let's say i check the checkbox of player 3, player 4 get 30 minutes instead of 3.

Comment: Add some debug code to check the full list of values that are coming through from the variable. e.g. foreach ($_POST['rooduit'] as $key=>$value) { echo "$key : $value <br>"; }

Comment: It may be that adding the hidden variables is messing up the length or order of the array being posted.

Comment: i agree. But the strange thing is that the '0' value isn't replaced by the '30' when the checkbox is checked. It looks like it doesn't replace it just add it to the array and it end up with the next player in the array. (btw, i wanted to start chat to avoid the extended discussion but I doesn't have enough rep points)

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply with 1 where you get the POST

```
$checkbox=$_POST['checkbox']*1;
```

So you will get 0 if the checkbox was not checked.

Another solution is to check if the $_POST is set:

```
if(!isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
$checkbox=0;
}else{
$checkbox=$_POST['checkbox'];
}
```

Comment: Option 1 gives me: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /home/srzaorg/public_html/test.php on line 256

Comment: Option 2 gives me:
UPDATE dbo_Deelnemers SET MinutenStrafVerwerkt = MinutenStrafVerwerkt+'10' WHERE Deelnemer = '2202'UPDATE dbo_Deelnemers SET MinutenStrafVerwerkt = MinutenStrafVerwerkt+'' WHERE Deelnemer = '4434'

So from the second one it contains no value (i selected checkbox nine btw)

Comment: Option 1:
Then you have error_reporting set to E_ALL & E_STRICT

Try the following (please replace 'checkbox' with the name of the checkbox in your form, and use $checkbox_val in your SQL for updating):

$checkbox_val=0;
if(isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
 if($_POST['checkbox']!=''){
  $checkbox_val=30;
}
}

Comment: UPDATE dbo_Deelnemers SET MinutenStrafVerwerkt = MinutenStrafVerwerkt+'' WHERE Deelnemer = '5023'

Query remains empty, not even 0 is insert

Comment: Sorry, i did not see, that you post the values as array roodthuis[] so this would of course not work. You will always have just the checked boxed in this array and the others not.

So when the second checkbox is checked roodthuis[0] will keep the value, but when the first checkbox is checked roodthuis[0] will be the value of the first and roodthuis[1] will be the value of the next checked box. Better will be to forget about the field Deelnemerthuis[] and use field names like data[622][NaamCombithuis], data[622][doelpuntthuis] and so far...

Comment: i'm not sure i understand what you're saying stocker4all. Are you saying that i'll need to change:
<input name="Deelnemerthuis[]" type="hidden" id="Deelnemerthuis" size="10" value="<? echo $rowthuis['Deelnemer']; ?>" readonly>
in to:
<input name="data[$rowthuis['Deelnemer']" type="hidden" id="Deelnemerthuis" size="10" value="<? echo $rowthuis['Deelnemer']; ?>" readonly>

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it with change the checkbox to a dropdown selection. Not optimal but workable. Thanx for the help guys!